# Change responsive row height

Tags: datatable

I'm using datatable to display data. I have done one example that could be found here:

```
`Example`  https://jsfiddle.net/hstcpj4b/
```

My question is, is it possible to change the row height (and remove the lines in the body when the table is in responsive mode), see picture.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2dx8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can set max-height !important in your css property

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How do I write these in the ccs file?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code :

```
container.find(".dataTables_scrollBody").css('height', container.height() - 20);
```